# Image not showing with a standalone bokeh server using BokehTornado instance configured with StaticFileHandler

Tags: bokeh, tornado, python-3.8

This is a follow up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62628332/4015990).

The structure of the files is shown below. I have to run the scripts using `python -m bokeh_module.bokeh_sub_module` from the top directory. The `image.png` might come from an arbitrary directory later.

```
.
├── other_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── other_sub_module.py
├── bokeh_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── image.png # not showing
│   └── bokeh_sub_module.py
└── image.png # not showing either
```

The bokeh_sub_module.py is using the standalone bokeh server. However the image will not show no matter where it is placed. I got this `WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 0.50ms` I'm not sure if this an issue from bokeh or tornado. Thank you for any help.

```
from other_module import other_sub_module
import os
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
import tornado.web

def make_document(doc):
    def update():
        pass

    # do something with other_sub_module
    p = figure(match_aspect=True)
    p.image_url( ['file://image.png'], 0, 0, 1, 1)
    doc.add_root(column(p, sizing_mode='stretch_both'))
    doc.add_periodic_callback(callback=update, period_milliseconds=1000)


apps = {'/': make_document}
application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/(.*)", \
                                      tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, \
                                      {"path": os.path.dirname(__file__)}),])
server = Server(apps, tornado_app=application)
server.start()
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
server.io_loop.start()
```

I tried the argument [extra_patterns](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py#L47) and it does not work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `file://` protocol with web servers and browsers. Just use regular `http://` or `https://`. If you specify the correct URL, the `StaticFileHandler` should properly handle it.

Apart from that, your usage of `Server` is not correct. It doesn't have the `tornado_app` argument. Instead, pass the routes directly:

```py
extra_patterns = [(r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
                   {"path": os.path.dirname(__file__)})]
server = Server(apps, extra_patterns=extra_patterns)
```

BTW just in case - in general, you shouldn't serve the root of your app. Otherwise, anyone would be able to see your source code.

Comment: I tried to replace `file://` with `http://` and `https://`, neither of them show the image. Thanks any way.

Comment: You don't just replace them, you should use a proper URL. With that being said, a relative URL should also work. Just try to use `'/image.png'` as a URL.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I just tried using `'/image.png'`, but with no luck. It says `404 GET /image.png`.

Comment: `'http://localhost:5006/image.png'` does not work either...